# C shell history function overwrite and pointer misplacement

Tags: c, shell, pointers, command-line, overwrite

I'm new to C, and I'm using C to create a simple shell. It's working well, but I'm struggling to implement a history function. My first issue is that the history overwrites itself, almost randomly, as it seems that the most recent command replaces previous commands, as seen here:

```
osh> ocf test
osh> ocf test1
osh> orm test
osh> orm test1
osh> ohistory
  5 ohistory
  4 orm
  3 orm
  2 orm
  1 orm
osh> ohistory
  6 ohistory
  5 ohistory
  4 ohistory
  3 orm
  2 ohistory
  1 ohistory
```

The second issue is that only the first argument of commands is being saved, but I want both elements to be saved. I think that the issue is with my pointers. It seems that I'm only printing the content of a pointer, but my arguments are `**args`, so I think it's only using the first thing pointed to. However, my understanding of pointers is SEVERELY limited, and I can't wrap my head around the info online. Necessary code below (if more is needed, I'll add happily, I just don't want this post to be too long):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* The maximum length command */

int should_run = 1; /* flag to determine when to exit program */

int command_count = 0;

struct node {
  char* cmd;
  int count;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *current = NULL;

...

int ohistory() {
  struct node *ptr = head;
  while(ptr != NULL) {
    printf("  %d\t%s\n", ptr->count, ptr->cmd);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
  return 1;
}

int history_insert(int count, char* cmd) {
  struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  if(link == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for new node\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  link->cmd = cmd;
  link->count = count;
  link->next = head;

  head = link;
  return 1;
}

int execute(char **args) {
  int i;

  if (args[0] == NULL) {
    // An empty command was entered.
    return 1;
  }

  int len = sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(builtin_str[0]);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
      command_count++;
      history_insert(command_count, *args);
      return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
    }
  }
  return launch(args);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char **args; /* command line arguments */
  char *command;
  int status;

  while (should_run) {
    printf("osh> ");

    command = read_line();
    args = parse(command);
    status = execute(args);

    free(command);
    free(args);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I've been working on this for several days. I've been using stackoverflow for years, but this is the first time I've ever posted (if that gives you any indication of how lost I am).

Comment: Is `args[0]` a pointer into `command` (like `strtok()` would create)? You're saving this pointer in `history`, but then you're freeing the memory with `free(command);`.

Comment: `history_insert()` should make a copy of the command.

Comment: @Barmar yes, args[0] is a pointer into command. I removed `free(command);`, and I've added `  char *dest = malloc(strlen(cmd) + 1);
strcpy(dest, cmd);` to `history_insert()`. The overwriting is no longer happening, thanks! Do you see why I might not be picking up all parts of the command, though?